# Run-time error '3464': Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to create a report with `date` as a criterium.

I have a TextBox (unbound) named `ber-datum` and i want to select every entry in my table thats matches with the date.

I created a button with the following code behind it.

```
Private Sub ber_datum_button_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "ber-planung", acViewReport, , "[Datum]='" & Me.[ber-datum] & "'"
End Sub
```

But im always getting the "Data type mismatch" error. 
The data type of `Datum` in my table is set to Date.

Every other report works fine except this one.

Example:

```
Private Sub ber_hid_button_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "ber-planung", acViewReport, , "[HID]='" & Me.[ber-hid] & "'"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Date expressions must be wrappen in octothorpes:

```
Private Sub ber_datum_button_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "ber-planung", acViewReport, , "[Datum]=#" & Format(Me![ber-datum].Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
End Sub
```